# Animated cloth simulation parenting troubles

Tags: animation, physics, parent

[image]

I have parented both banner (with a simulation), airplane and camera, but cannot make them travel in sync.

The flag/banner is making me troubles: The objects appear connected when moved 
in 3d-view, but the banner is lost behind when animated.

[Animated example (gif)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1K5mqdGel6HO8TSzGb6CiFIQPfgxF_pye)

[Please download blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YCjTY7rxxDv07Bq-OPh3vmeLx0RB6v5b)

Appreciate any help.

Kind regards,
Raaskot

Comment: What are using for flag wavering, cloth modifier or displacing? Seems like cloth isn't pinned properly to follow motion.

Comment: You have uploaded your gif, not the .blend file.

Comment: Sorry, I messed the links up. Thanks both of you :-)
Yet, I took a break, returned to the file and figured out the problem: pure noob-ism of my own ;-)
Please have a look at my edit above ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was quite simple. Didn't understand the nature of the baking process and how it worked when the physics object (plus forcefield) was a child of an moving parent (the camera).

Being a bit unexperienced in the physics field I did'nt understand the obvious necessity baking the flag / running the entire animation.

[image: Bake command]

After executing this the flag catched up fine.

Thanks for your kind attention: Often a matter of verbalization of the problem brings one close to the truth -- and solution :-)